# Why different .Net Core SDK for Visual Studio 2017 and 2019?

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core

I needed to install .Net Core SDK 2.2 for a new project. I was using VS2017 and I installed dotnet-sdk-2.2.203-win-x64 which did not work. It never showed up on the Target Framework in my project properties. Removing that, I installed dotnet-sdk-2.2.106-win-x64 which worked.

That made me realize that there are different .net core installers for VS 2017 and 2019. Refer: https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/visual-studio-sdks?utm_source=getdotnetsdk&utm_medium=referral

I wonder why is that so? Could someone tell or direct to some blog/documentation?

Thanks!

Comment: The installer places the files in different directories depending upon which application you are using.   There may also be some registry settings for it as well.   Things like this are application version specific

Comment: Thanks for comments. I can see the reason for different directories/settings, but I wonder if there is a dependency on MSBuild and .Net Core SDK!!!